# how can I parse json with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
[{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557704","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557705","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557706","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557707","mobile":"400089151"}]
```

I need to extract all "phoneNumber" using a js function.
I'm testing from using html and my function is not so good:

```
function getNumbers(strJSON)
{   
            strJSON = "[{\"errorMessage\":\"success\",\"mobile\":\"400089151\",\"phoneNumber\":\"400557704\",\"returnCode\":\"0\"},{\"errorMessage\":\"success\",\"mobile\":\"400089151\",\"phoneNumber\":\"400557705\",\"returnCode\":\"0\"},{\"errorMessage\":\"success\",\"mobile\":\"400089151\",\"phoneNumber\":\"400557706\",\"returnCode\":\"0\"}]";

        var len = strJSON.length;

        var begin_index = strJSON.indexOf("returnCode") - 2;
        var last_index = len - 1;
        var string_toSplit = strJSON.substring(begin_index, last_index);
        var string_splitted = string_toSplit.split("{");
        var out="";

        alert(strJSON);
        alert("string_splitted");
        alert(string_splitted);
        for ( var i = 0; i < string_splitted.length; i++) 
        {
            if (string_splitted[i].charAt(string_splitted[i].length - 1) === ",") 
            {
                string_splitted[i] = string_splitted[i].slice(0, -1);
            }
            var json = "{" + string_splitted[i];
            var obj = JSON.parse(json);
            if (i == string_splitted.length) 
            {
                out = out + obj.phoneNumber;
            } 
            else
            {
                out = out + obj.phoneNumber + ",";
            }
        }
        return out;     

}
```

Comment: Are you try something? Or just wait how someone do your homework?

Comment: I don't see a question here.  What have you tried?

Comment: Even if the initial question didn't contain all the details, all these wild downvotes to welcome a new user are totally unnecessary :-(

Comment: @Christophe totally agree.

Answer (score 3):

For modern browsers you can use the [`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var j = [{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557704","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557705","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557706","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557707","mobile":"400089151"}];

var phones = j.map(function(item){return item.phoneNumber});
```

---

**Update**

After seeing your code (*do not try to manually split/parse the json string.. use the `JSON.parse` method*) you should use

```
function getNumbers(strJSON)
{   
    var myJson = JSON.parse( strJSON );
    return myJson.map(function( item ){ return item.phoneNumber}).join(',');   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: An even better way:

```
function getNumbers(strJSON)
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(strJSON);   

    return obj.map(x => x.phoneNumber).join(", ")
}
```

Original Post:

A straight forward method is to just iterate over every object in the array and take the values out individually.

```
var info = [{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557704","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557705","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557706","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557707","mobile":"400089151"}];


var phoneNumbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
{
    phoneNumbers.push(info[i].phoneNumber);
}

console.log(phoneNumbers);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hX69r/

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/hX69r/1/

```
var info = [{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557704","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557705","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557706","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557707","mobile":"400089151"}];

var infoString = JSON.stringify(info); //this just turns the object array 'info' into a string

var numbers = getNumbers(infoString);
console.log(numbers);

function getNumbers(strJSON)
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(strJSON);

    var phoneNumbers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    {
        phoneNumbers.push(obj[i].phoneNumber);
    }

    return phoneNumbers.join(", ");
}
```

Additional Update:

```
var info = [{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557704","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557705","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557706","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557707","mobile":"400089151"}];

var infoSingle = {"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557704","mobile":"400089151"};

console.log(info.length); // prints 4; so you know it has the []
console.log(infoSingle.length); // prints undefined; so you know it doesn't have []
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Maybe you can help me solving my problem. I want to use this function in a vxml code and I'm using something like this : <assign name="AppState.out" expr="test(AppState.out)" /> where out = 'info' from your function and test is the name of the function. My response AppState.out is like this : ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, Could you help me?

Comment: I have one more question. If my JSON has one time two sets of values like this [{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557704","mobile":"400089151"},
{"returnCode":"0","errorMessage":"success","Code":{},"phoneNumber":"400557706","mobile":"400089151"},];
and some time only one set of values like this {"errorMessage":"success","msisdn":"233714735","phoneNumber":"230557707","returnCode":"0"} how can I make it work, because when I have only one set of values [] are missing.

Comment: I updated the code up above to answer this question. Just keep in mind that if the questions are different in scope, you should consider posting another question all together. So in my update you can see that checking info.length returns a value and infoSingle.length returns undefined. My suggestion is to make it -always- return an array ([]) even if it only has 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to re-invent the wheel.

There are many ways to parse JSON already:

- **Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).**
- **Use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)**